# Is it better to put queries in models.py or views.py

Tags: django

I wanted to make a query

```
query = Rating.objects.filter(human=pk)

friendliness = query.aggregate(Avg('friendliness'))
punctuality = query.aggregate(Avg('punctuality'))
knowledge = query.aggregate(Avg('knowledge'))
```

and show this in my html. Is the best practice to put it in views.py or is it better to put it in models.py?

Comment: better in model, you can easy reuse it.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you might find this article useful
http://scottlobdell.me/2015/01/sql-database-best-practices-django-orm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is best suited for `models.Manager`:

```
class RatingManager(models.Manager):
    ...
    def aggregate_by_friendliness(self, human):
        return self.filter(human=human).aggregate(Avg('friendliness'))

class Rating(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = RatingManager()
```

So you can reuse it like this:

```
friendliness = Rating.objects.aggregate_by_friendliness(human=pk)
```

Comment: thank you. To make it reusable, I made a variable to replace 'friendliness'

`class RatingManager(models.Manager):
    ...
    def aggregate_by_friendliness(self, human, category):
        return self.filter(human=human).aggregate(Avg(category))`